# convert NSArray to MKPlacemark

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkplacemark

I have a forward geocode block. like this:

```
[_geoCoder geocodeAddressString:searchString completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {....}];
```

As is, the geocode data stores in the `NSArray *` placemarks. Now I would like to do some annotation to the map, The `addAnnotation` method requires a `MKPlacemark`, so how do I convert the place mark in `NSArray`into a `MKPlacemark`? Thanks.

Comment: @vadian: No, it contains CLPlacemark objects: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clgeocodecompletionhandler

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want to do: Iterate through the parameters array - meaning, fetch each item from the array. As we're fetching the items, we want to create MKPlacemark objects using the data the items contain.

The Objective-C language gives us a special tool that allows us to iterate through the array - the "forin" loop:

```
for (CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks)
{
// insert code here
}
```

Now, we want to create an MKPlacemark object from "placemark": (Note: An MKPlacemark object *is* a CLPlacemark object)

```
MKPlacemark *mkPlacemark = [MKPlacemark initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate 
                 addressDictionary:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)addressDictionary;]
```